# Pointwise mutual information for text using R

Tags: r, text-mining, mutual-information

I have key-value pairs of text. The values can be multiple words (n-grams). For example,

```
A     abcd
A     efgh
B     abcd
C     wxyz
C     mnop
```

I want to calculate [Pointwise Mutual Information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointwise_mutual_information) for the pairs. Is there a function in R to do this? Otherwise, how can I go about it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There are many functions for estimating the mutual information or the entropy in R, for example the entropy package. Enter

```
install.packages("entropy")
```

at the R-prompt.
You can then use the property that
$pmi(x;y) = h(x) + h(y) - h(xy) $
to calculate the pointwise mutual information.
You need to obtain frequency estimates for the two random variables first.

Comment: This will give you the mutual information between the random variables, not the pointwise mutual information between the pairs.